# How to import dynamic numbers of CSV files in Excel?

Tags: excel, csv, vba

I have created a macro which takes input as only a "certain defined number" of CSV files. But in case the number of CSV files vary then it creates an issue.

E.g. in a current month I have 6 CSV files to import but next month it may be more than 6 . In that case, it only imports only 6 files.

Can you please help me with a dynamic code which can import a different number of CSV files.

Regards,
Alok

Comment: Please share your code. It's not easy to help without knowing how you are importing the data now.

Comment: Show us what you already have.